# What is keeping the stock market high?

Tags: stocks

With unemployment spikes, housing going forbearance, personal debt increasing at record rate, corporate debt at historic height. The simple question is despite all the bad news out there why is the stock market keep going up?  Why is the demand for stock investments so high?

Comment: As written this seems very subjective (and therefore off-topic). Reasons to explain the ups and downs of the markets vary widely.

Comment: well, you dont know what you dont know. you cant expect there would be narrowed questions. Fed for example would be one of the factor why market is up.

Comment: One could just as well ask why so many investors were willing to sell shares, driving the price down, allowing more rational investors to buy otherwise solid stocks at discounted prices.

Comment: I would like to reopen this question as I have an answer that is very illustrative about the market and consumer issues.  it will not be opinion based.

Comment: By any historical measure, the market should be lower.  Unemployment is massive, corporate profits have disappeared in many sectors.  GDP is dropping.  IT aint pretty out there.   However, there has been an unprecedented amount of  stimulus thrown at the market .  So either everyone drank the Kool Aid or the market, which is forward looking, sees better times sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: While unemployment is high and all the other problems exist, they're not really what we might call structural problems.  That is, there's the belief (justified or not) among many people that the COVID-19 situation is going to go away soon, either by a Trumpian miracle or the development of vaccines, and things will return to "normal".

Comment: @PeteB. - all due respect, ok.

Comment: Despite Pete's answer, I don't think this is on topic.  The actual answer is primarily due to economics and action by the Fed, which is not on topic here.

Comment: It's as simple as these words in Bob's comment: "The market is forward looking"

Comment: Basically nothing has changed for the long term aspect of the companies that people believe are strong enough to go through this wave. So, people keep buying.

Answer (score 2):

The market will continue to go up as long as there are more buyers than sellers, due to the laws of supply and demand.

The market is not the economy. A lot of the bad news are already priced in and the demand reflects the hopes and expectations for the quarters/years to come. The assumptions might be overly optimistic but only time will tell.

Additionally, there has been a lot of fiscal/monetary stimulus to support the economy and market valuations.

Answer (score -1):

Fear is a very powerful emotion and the news media uses it to help their advertisers sell products.  After all that is who the news media works for. 
 One is mistaken if they believe the media's job is to provide accurate information. 
 Fear is highly effective when it comes to selling.

While there is certainly some bad news there is also good news.  For example COVID-19 deaths are an order of magnitude lower then originally reported.  While racial tensions are high after a couple of incidents justice is progress in the two case I am thinking about.  That is good news.

While there have been a lot of layoffs, most of those are lower paying jobs that have a less dramatic effect on the economy.  Will they be hired back quickly?  Probably.  Many higher paying jobs are working from home either part or full time so people have more disposable income and time to spend.

It all depends upon one's perspective.  Two people can view a story and both can walk away with very different emotions.  One must be very careful at taking the media at face value and look for the story within the story.

This is my opinion but I think we are in for another correction shortly.  When the bad economic data comes out for certain companies next earning season, the will be panic selling.  That will be a great time to buy and stock values will likely recover quickly.  However, I could be very wrong.

The best approach to investing is to ignore the media, invest part of your income regularly, and let it grow.  Efforts to time and trade are futile.  Regular investments in low cost index funds and time will make you wealthy.